# How do I stop Liquid XML automatically loading schemas to validate my XML document

Tags: liquid-xml

When I open an XML document Liquid XML automatically starts loading the associated schemas from its internal standard library, but I want it to use my schemas as we are working with a modified version of the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some occasions you may not want a standard schemas to be used to to provide validation and intellisense for your XML Document. This may be for performance reasons, or because you have modified the standard, or maybe the standard uses the same namespace for all its versions (it happens more than you think), and the version in the library is not the one you are using.

In order to stop this happening:

1. Run the Liquid XML application.
2. Create a new XML Document (File->New File...->XML Document)
3. Select Tools->Schema Used to Validate XML. A dialog showing the schemas in the library should appear.
4. Find the schema you don't want to use from the library and ensure it is unchecked or use the 'Remove Standard' button to remove it from the library altogether.

You can create a new Schema Library Entry for your version of the schemas See [Can I automatically associate an XSD schema with an XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611195/can-i-automatically-associate-an-xsd-schema-with-an-xml-document/41611196#41611196)